# Android, change view and take screenshot

Tags: java, android, android-layout, screenshot, android-view

I want to change the visibility of a view from `GONE` to `VISIBLE` and take a screenshot of my whole application and save it in a file.

I'm able to take the screenshot, but the view remain not visible (`GONE`) in the jpeg file. The method is called from a button click:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    View screen = (View) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);    

    //I change this from View.GONE
    TextView hiddenText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hiddenText);
    hiddenText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    hiddenText.setText( "WEEEEEEEEEE" + (int)(Math.random()*10) );

    View rootview = screen.getRootView();
    //View rootview = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    rootview.invalidate();  //I try to redraw the view without success
    rootview.requestLayout();
    rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = rootview.getDrawingCache();                 
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);                                                 
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + 
              File.separator + "Facebook" + File.separator + "my_screenshot.jpeg";
    File file = new File(path);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); //if the folder doesn't exists it's created

    try {
        boolean asd = file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ostream.write(bytes.toByteArray()); 
        ostream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //hiddenText.setVisibility(View.GONE);                      
}
```

After that I save the file I should hide again the TextView `hiddenText`, but I doesn't know in which point to set the visibility `GONE`.

Comment: You need to wait until your `setVisibility()` change has taken effect before taking your screenshot.

Comment: @Accollativo try to change the visibility first and than get main screen handle like `View screen = hiddenText.getParent();` I am assuming that textView parent is `R.id.mainLayout`

Comment: kamil doesn't work. @CommonsWare how can I wait?

Comment: @Accollativo Can you post your xml code?

Comment: "how can I wait?" -- probably by moving the screenshot stuff into [a `ViewTreeObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html).

Comment: @kamil it's not useful the xml, it's really simple one button an one textview with         android:visibility="gone"

Comment: @CommonsWare I discovered another possible solution, I think it is faster adding some text or image to the Bitmap.